# Using Custom Legend Symbol in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, legend, story-map, arcgis-online-webmap

I am currently creating an ArcGIS Online Journal story map. In one of the web maps, I have a point feature class, where the points are transparent and they provide labels for regions (with no clear boundaries, hence no polygons). I need the legend to show one of the labels instead. This way, the legend symbol would be an example of the label text.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you include some screenshots to show what you are seeing now and what you would like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, legends are one of the most limited features of ArcGIS story maps and ArcGIS Online maps in general. Beyond a few very basic options, you really can't customize legends as the titles and legend components are pulled from your layer services. The official Esri "solution" is to either:

1. Turn off the legend and replace it with a graphic in the side panel of your story map. Usually, the easiest thing to do is to replicate the symbology you want in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro and then take a screenshot of a legend you produce there. It's a bit of a clunky workaround, but works OK. Here's an example of [a story map](https://univofillinois.maps.arcgis.com/apps/Cascade/index.html?appid=a58c2043100d4f3a891dc83d9bc00c2e) that uses graphics placed in a scrolling sidebar.
2. Manually style your legend using CSS.

Examples of both workarounds are shown in an Esri blog post titled [Enhance your Story Map Journal legend](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/uncategorized/enhance-your-story-map-journal-legend/?rmedium=redirect&rsource=blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/12/16/enhance-legend-story-map-journal).

Comment: I've chosen to accept this answer, because the first option did the job quite nicely. I haven't tried the second option, but it could be a very useful tip for other people.

Comment: Glad that helped you @Matthew. That's the way I've gone in the past too. Usually the legends I need to make are not so complex that a custom styled legend using CSS is worth the time or effort. Taking a screenshot of a legend from ArcMap is a kludge, but it works OK. Hopefully one day Esri will add support for customizing legends in ArcGIS Online. It's a little mystifying that that's not an option already.